# How can I disable transition in codepipeline via CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I am using nodejs CDK to deploy codepipeline to AWS. Below is the code:

```js
const pipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, this.projectName, {
      pipelineName: this.projectName,
      role: this.pipelineRole,
      stages,
      artifactBucket: s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(
        this,
        'deploymentS3Bucket',
        cdk.Fn.importValue(this.s3Bucket)
      ),
    });
```

It has all stages defined inside `stages` array. The question I have is how to disable transition in one of the stage on this pipeline?

I tried below code:

```js
const primaryDeployStage: codepipeline.CfnPipeline = pipeline.node.findChild('Approve') as codepipeline.CfnPipeline;
      const stageTransitionProperty: codepipeline.CfnPipeline.StageTransitionProperty = {
        reason: 'reason',
        stageName: 'stageName',
      };
      primaryDeployStage. addPropertyOverride('DisableInboundStageTransitions', stageTransitionProperty);
```

but it says `no such method addOverride` error.

Comment: Assuming this transition is not disabled forever, have you considered a manual approval step for this use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of CDK v2.1, the `codepipeline.Pipeline` class does not expose this property, but the Level1 `CfnPipeline` class it builds on does ([github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1649)).

**Option 1:  Quick and dirty workaround:** reach into `codepipeline.Pipeline`'s implementation to get a reference to its `CfnPipeline` (this is the approach you tried):

```js
// pipeline is a codepipeline.Pipeline
// DANGER - 'Resource' is the CfnPipeline construct's id, assigned in the Pipeline's constructor implementation
const cfnPipeline = pipeline.node.findChild('Resource') as codepipeline.CfnPipeline;

cfnPipeline.addPropertyOverride('DisableInboundStageTransitions', [
  {
    StageName: 'Stage2',
    Reason: 'No particular reason',
  },
]);
```

**Option 2: instantiate a Level1 [CfnPipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.CfnPipeline.html)**, which accepts a [disableInboundStageTransitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.CfnPipelineProps.html#disableinboundstagetransitions) prop.

```js
// CfnPipelineProps
disableInboundStageTransitions: [{
  reason: 'reason',
  stageName: 'stageName',
}],
```

---

##### Edit:  Explain that `Resource` is the name of the `CfnPipeline` child node

We disable stage transitions by passing stage names to a L1 `CfnPipeline`.  Approach #2 does this directly by creating one.
But we'd rather use a L2 `Pipeline`, because it's easier.  This is Approach #1, the one you are taking.  Lucky for us, our `pipeline` has a `CfnPipeline` child node named 'Resource'.  How do we know this?  We look in the
[Pipeline constructor's source code on github](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/4e7a2758eec6999aee5432b3e9e6bbe7626a2d6b/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline/lib/pipeline.ts#L403).
Once we have a reference to the `CfnPipeline` using `pipeline.node.findChild('Resource')`, we add the disabled stages to it as a property override, in the same `{StageName:  Reason:}` format as in #2.

Comment: I tried your option1 but I got `addPropertyOverride is not a function` error.

Comment: [addPropertyOverride](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_codepipeline.CfnPipeline.html#addwbrpropertywbroverridepropertypath-value) is a documented method on `codepipeline.CfnPipeline`.  It has been [documented escape hatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html#cfn_layer_raw) syntax on the parent class `CfnResource` since 2019.  Make sure you are properly casting with `as codepipeline.CfnPipeline`.  I can't comment on your invisible code, but can confirm the answer's code compiles and deploys as expected without error.

Comment: Another thought:  make sure you are passing `'Resource'` as the child name in `pipeline.node.findChild('Resource')`, as the code comment explains. Passing `'Approve'` as you did in the OP will not work.

Comment: There are multiple stages in my pipeline and what does `Resource` mean? I just want to disable transition in one stage not all.

Comment: Yeah, we found your problem!  `Resource` is the name AWS's devs gave to `pipeline's` `CfnPipeline` child.  I added an explainer to my answer.  My original answer works - just add the stage names you wish to disable to the `addPropertyOverride` array!